# jQuery does not trigger on Meteor Application after you do a page refresh in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to implement [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Podgro/pen/GoWJqN) into my Meteor app which I run with blaze.

I'm running into a problem where if I click on the Floating Action Button after a page refresh, nothing happens.

If I leave the page then go back it works fine. However every time I Ctrl + R or refresh the browser by hitting the refresh button, the jQuery will not run anymore.

My implementation of the CodePen code is pretty much exactly the same so I've narrowed this issue down to something with Meteor and the way it renders templates.

I've tried a few things so far:

1) Put it in a $(window).load()

2) Put in in a $(document).ready()

3) I've put it outside the Template.onRendered function

Here's the jQuery that's supposed to run when the plus button is clicked, the full code is in the CodePen link as well

```
$(".action").click(function(){
        // $(".content1").addClass("inactive").delay(200).fadeOut(0);
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).closest("div").find(".content2").fadeIn(0).addClass("active");
    });

 $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".content2").removeClass("active").delay(300).fadeOut(0);
        $(".action").removeClass("active");
        // $(".content1").fadeIn(0).removeClass("inactive");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I placed that jQuery in the events section and it worked.

```
Template.TempName.events({    
'click .action': function (event, instance) {
            alert('hello');
            // $(".content1").addClass("inactive").delay(200).fadeOut(0);
            $('.action').addClass("active");
            // $(this).closest("div").find(".content2").fadeIn(0).addClass("active");
        },
});
```